# Complete Boolean algebras and second-countability

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra

In Wikipedia's article "Complete Boolean algebra, the following example is given:

> The Boolean algebra of all Baire sets modulo meager sets in a topological space with a countable base is complete...

This suggests that the Boolean algebra of all Baire sets modulo meager sets in a topological space *without* a countable base may not be complete.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, consider an uncountable discrete space $X$.  The compact $G_\delta$ subsets of $X$ are just the finite sets, so the Baire sets are the sets which are countable or cocountable.  The only meager set is $\emptyset$, so the Baire sets modulo meager sets are again the countable or cocountable sets.  This algebra is not complete (for instance, if you take a subset $Y\subset X$ which is neither countable nor cocountable, the join of all countable subsets of $Y$ does not exist).

Comment: Thanks for the example. Suppose now that the Boolean algebra of all Baire sets modulo meager sets of the original post is ccc. Then it is complete regardless whether or not the space is second-countable, right?

Comment: Yes, since a ccc $\sigma$-algebra is complete.